# Scheduled class on post install

Tags: apex, managed-package, scheduled-apex, appexchange

In my managed package I am scheduling a  class in the post install. For some reason, any code changes to the scheduled class that I push to the managed package do not take effect when I am trying to upgrade the package in the client org.

Things work perfectly fine when I install fresh package after uninstalling the existing version.

Only thing my post install class does is scheduling the class. Is is possible that the scheduler only takes a particular version of the class while scheduling. So even if the class changes while the scheduler is running, it will pick the previous version only.

This can't be replicated in the dev org as the changes to the scheduled class wont even save if it is scheduled.

Just wanted to know if in the post install, stopping the already running scheduler and restarting it again will help?

Comment: Is the [Allow deployments of components when corresponding Apex jobs are pending or in progress](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_deploy_with_jobs.htm) setting on?